# What specifications does my iPhone 5c require to charge?

Tags: battery

I'm looking into portable battery packs and I was looking into the electrical specifications of the pack. This got be thinking what current and voltage does my 5c need to charge?

Comment: most portable battery packs will say if they work for iphones

Comment: Thanks. But I was looking for the amps and volts required as some day may build my own solar charger pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here or the specifications used by Apple's official charging cords.

5 volts  1.0 amps
If your interested in making one for iPads you can use
5.1 Volts and 2.1 Amps

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3511)

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter. As long as it is 5 Volts DC. The iPhone will choose the current by itself. I use generic 5V buck converters, like [this one](http://www.prodctodc.com/dc-to-dc-724-v-to-5v-2a-buck-converter-car-power-supply-usb-output-module-p-109.html), to charge from my solar system.